# DataFrame: Moving average with rolling, mean and shift while ignoring NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data, moving-average

I have a data set, let's say, 420x1. Now I would to calculate the moving average of the past 30 days, excluding the current date.

If I do the following:

```
df.rolling(window = 30).mean().shift(1)
```

my df results in a window with lots of NaNs, which is probably caused by NaNs in the original dataframe here and there (1 NaN within the 30 data points results the MA to be NaN).

Is there a method that ignores NaN (avoiding apply-method, I run it on large data so performance is key)? I do not want to replace the value with 0 because that could skew the results.

the same applies than to moving standard deviation.

Comment: 30 actual days?  Business days?  Where is the sample data?

Comment: business days only captured; so i need an "offset" of 30 rows before.

Comment: You still aren't providing any sample data.

Comment: apologies, you can also use R.yan's example data. it's exactly that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example you can adding `min_periods`, and `NaN` is gone

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,np.nan,2,3,4,np.nan]})
df.A.rolling(window=2,min_periods=1).mean()

Out[7]: 
0    1.0
1    1.5
2    2.5
3    3.0
4    2.0
5    2.5
6    3.5
7    4.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks, Wen. If I use min_periods = 1, does that mean the program is then using 29 observations to calculate the average?

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

```
df.dropna().rolling('30D').mean()
```

### Option 2

```
df.interpolate('index').rolling('30D').mean()
```

### Option 2.5

```
df.interpolate('index').rolling(30).mean()
```

### Option 3

```
s.rolling('30D').apply(np.nanmean)
```

### Option 3.5

```
df.rolling(30).apply(np.nanmean)
```

Comment: thanks, piRSquared, I think option 3 and 3.5 is rather what I am looking for. Same question as below to R.yan: when applying np.nanmean, is the window still, i.e. 3, 3, NaN or is NaN getting dropped and the value after NaN used instead (or since we are looking back the value before the first 3)?

Comment: Assuming a window of 30, if 10 were nan, it would find the mean of the other 20.

Comment: min_periods is the canonical; using apply is quite inefficient fyi

Comment: @eternity1 per Jeff’s comment, can you accept wen’s answer instead?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to remove the nan values or [fillna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace the nan with specific value.

Or you can filter out all nan value by [notnull()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) or [isnull()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) within your operation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), index=['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h'],columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
df2 = df.reindex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
print df2
        one       two     three
a  0.434024 -0.749472 -1.393307
b       NaN       NaN       NaN
c  0.897861  0.032307 -0.602912
d       NaN       NaN       NaN
e -1.056938 -0.129128  1.328862
f -0.581842 -0.682375 -0.409072
g       NaN       NaN       NaN
h -1.772906 -1.342019 -0.948151

df3 = df2[df2['one'].notnull()]
# use ~isnull() would return the same result
# df3 = df2[~df2['one'].isnull()]
print df3
    one       two     three
a  0.434024 -0.749472 -1.393307
c  0.897861  0.032307 -0.602912
e -1.056938 -0.129128  1.328862
f -0.581842 -0.682375 -0.409072
h -1.772906 -1.342019 -0.948151
```

For further reference, Pandas has a clean documentary about handling missing data(read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html)).

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I do not want to drop the observation nor to fill it with another value (unless there is no way out). It's like calculating an average but ignoring the missing value (3 + 3 + NaN) / 2 = 3, instead of (3 + 3 + 0) / 3 = 2

Comment: So (3+3+NaN)/3 = 2, is it what you want?

Comment: yes, since the window, i.e. is 3 here, it should account the NaN, instead of taking another value in there for this particular window calculation